# class-validator in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, class-validator

I am trying to use class-validator package in my node project and somehow it is not being recognized.
It throws an error

```
 @MinLength(10, {
    ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Here is what I'm doing:

```
    const classValidator = require('class-validator');
    
    module.exports = class Entity{
        @MinLength(10, {
            message: 'Title is too short',
          })
          @MaxLength(50, {
            message: 'Title is too long',
          })
}
```

Comment: The error suggests that `@MinLength` is an unexpected token. That means Node.js can't understand the use of decorators. Decorators are not part of the language yet. You can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48055771/how-do-i-use-and-apply-javascript-decorators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Decorators are not part of the language yet" as mentioned by @Abrar Hossain in the comments suffices your answer. In JavaScript they’re currently a `stage 2 proposal`, meaning they should be part of a future update to the language

But reading your code implies that you're using Decorators for schema validation purposes.
You can use other libraries such as [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup) and [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) which are as powerful as class-validator package.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow their documentation and import `MinLength` and `MaxLength` to avoid the Syntax error.

```
import { MinLength, MaxLength } from 'class-validator';
```